# Checkbox for multiple SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql

I use a checkbox to select multiple items from database.

**extras.php**

```php
<form action="core/process.php" method="POST" class="checkbox" > 
<?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM prices WHERE cat_id =1";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" checked="" value="' . $row["name"] . '">' . $row["name"] . '(s)<br><br>';
}
?>
```

**process.php**

```php
if (isset($_POST["checkbox"]))
{
    if (!empty($_POST['check_list']))
    {
        // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        foreach ($_POST['check_list'] as $selected)
        {
            $checked_items = $selected;
        }
        $items = implode(',', $_POST['check_list']);
```

Outputs:

```
'item1', 'item2', 'item3'
```

I want to find a way to get details for item1, item2, item3 from my database table. These items exist in the table.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Your Sql query will be below

```
SELECT * FROM prices WHERE name IN ( $items ); // $items = 'item1', 'item2', 'item3'
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a some kind of software or a small billing software then you have to insert the different items in the different rows in database like:

```
---------------------------------
bill_no | item_no | item_quantity
1001    | 3       | 5
1001    | 15      | 1
1001    | 7       | 3
1001    | 1       | 10
---------------------------------
```

This is easy to maintain. Because it will not increase your code size and you will not have to use the implode or explode or foreach functions at every step. If you have the vast database then by this process you can finds the enteries from database quickly.